# Regex PHP sub pattern

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I can't get a sub pattern to work

```
preg_match_all("/<title>(\b\w{4,100}\b)<\/title>/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

I want to extract all the words from a title attribute which have more than 3 characters.

If I try the following expressions they both work. But as soon i want to put the last one as a sub pattern it doesn't output anything but 2 empty records in the array.

```
preg_match_all("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/", $input_lines, $output_array);

preg_match_all("/\b\w{4,100}\b/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

I'm using the following text an $input_lines

```
<title>This is a big test</title>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a two-step operation. First extract the title, then get the words.

```
if( preg_match("(<title>(.*?)</title>)i",$input_lines,$match)) {
    $title = $match[1];
    preg_match_all("/\w{4,}/",$title,$matches);
    $words = $matches[0];
}
```

Comment: @true Thank you for being my... uh... "outburst controller" XD

Comment: You're a hero! Was hoping to do it with one step, but looks like that was impossible. Thanks